# Is the Title attribute still used?

Tags: title-attribute

I'm curious if anyone still uses the Title attribute? I've noticed that none of the sites I visit on a regular basis use it at all, I'm talking about sites like ArsTechnica, The Verge, the BBC, etc...big triple-A sites. I found one random reference on the W3C's site to it being abused, is it just out of favor now or is there some specific reason?

Comment: The title attribute is still used based on the requirement. The title attribute is the HTML coding which gives/explains a little more information about the hyperlinked text. For more information refer to the following site:https://www.rankwatch.com/learning/content/215-is-title-attribute-really-important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute title is still in use, usually people choose to use it or not to use it for usability/design purposes (they might not like when text appears on hover).

Answer (score 3):

Title and alt have 2 different functions. Alt is used in place of broken images and can be read by "readers" for the blind. Title is used to display information about the picture or any other tag you feel like displaying a "tooltip" for. Some browsers will use the alt for their tooltip but this is browser specific and should not be counted on. If you want your viewers to see the tooltip for an image and are not using IE, there is a good chance they won't see it. This is why you should be using title as well.